# running linux kernel image with qemu

Tags: linux, terminal, console, kernel, qemu

I used these options to indicate which console to use by qemu

```
-nographic -serial stdio -append "console=ttyS0"
```

linux boot normally until this step, and when I hit enter the qemu> appear as the next picture illustrate:

[image]

It was me who types stop and quit

why did linux stop and qemu appear. I want to work with linux and execute programs from linux bin?

Comment: So whats your query..?

Comment: why did linux stop and qemu appear. I want to work with linux and execute programs from linux bin?

Comment: Can u paste your compleate command of qemu. and also mention for which architecture are u trying qemu and what step u followed to build kerne l Image and rootfs